# prestashop layered navigation block

Tags: prestashop, layered-navigation

normally layered navigation block is only displayed on a few pages like category page, search pages. However I want to show it in the "manufacturer" page/controller. If someone clicks the "manufacturer" menu to show up all the manufacturers, I want to show the "layered navigation" on the left column of the manufaturer controller.

Does someone know how to do that ?

I am using prestashop 1.5.6.2 and a premium responsive 3 column theme.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I believe its not possible, you might have to resort to a custom module for this. We tried to make it for manufacturer page some time back but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I want update this topic because now the addon to handle filtering on manufacturer product pages is available on official prestashop addons store and works perfectly :

[Download blocklayeredmanufacturer module here](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/product.php?id_product=19882)

Best Regards

Comment: I want add it's compatible only for prestashop 1.6.x version and I don't know if it works for you version if you have keep it outdated.
Best Regards